# Shellscript Read XML attribute value

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

We want to read XML attributes from an XML file. Example of file content is as below:

```
<properties>
  <property name="abc" value="15"/>
  <property name="xyz" value="26"/>
</properties>
```

We want to read value (i.e. 15) for property "abc" using shell script.
Please suggest shell commands to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What exactly do you want ? A function that returns 15 if you call `func(abc)` ? or a function that will parse your file and return `abc 15, xyz 26, ...` ?

Comment: it's better to use a xml parser rather than sed or awk.

Comment: You can have a look at [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to parse XML files, it has support for XPath.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a proper XML parser like xmllint. If your version supports xpath, it will be very easy to grab specific values. If it doesn't support xpath, then you can use `--shell` option like so:

```
$ echo 'cat //properties/property[@name="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxml
/ >  -------
 value="15"
/ >
```

You can then use `awk` or `sed` to format and extract desired field from output.

```
$ echo 'cat //properties/property[@name="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxmlfile | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}'
15
```

You can use command substitution to capture the output in a variable by saying:

```
$ myvar=$(echo 'cat //properties/property[@name="abc"]/@value' | xmllint --shell myxml | awk -F'[="]' '!/>/{print $(NF-1)}')
$ echo "$myvar"
15
```

Using anything else other than a xmlparser is prone to errors and will break easy.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty

```
sed -n '/<Properties>/,\|</properties>| {
   s/ *<property name="xyz" value="\([^"]*\)"\/>/\1/p
   }'
```

no xml check and based on your sample so assume same structure (one property name per line, ...)

posix version (`--posix` for GNU sed)

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n '/<property name="abc"/s/.*value="\(.*\)"[^\n]*/\1/p' file`

Creates a hold pattern for the value then matches everything except for the newline to avoid printing the newline, it expects the value double quoted as per your example data.

```
E.g. 
<properties>
  <property name="abc" value="15"/>
  <property name="xyz" value="26"/>
</properties>

Output:
15
```

(Prior to edit: `sed '/<property name="abc"/s/.*value="\(.*\)"[^\n]*/\1/' file`)

Comment: This is not working it gives output as    <properties> 15 <property name="xyz" value="26"/> </properties>

Comment: My error, it should have print and -n on there: sed -n '/<property name="abc"/s/.*value="\(.*\)"[^\n]*/\1/p' file